# IMAP Fetch Command - Returns all mail as Seen even when Unseen

Tags: gmail, imap, fetch, flags

I am downloading a message from Gmail using the following IMAP command:

```
UID FETCH 8590 (FLAGS UID RFC822.SIZE INTERNALDATE BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY)
```

Works great, except for one issue:

- Message **`FLAGS`** are always returned as **`Seen`** even when they are **`Unseen`**.

Is there something I missing from the command above to return
   correct flags for the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just checked with the exactly same command (except the UID) and I cannot reproduce that on my gmail account. Are you sure you aren't accessing other `BODY` items elsewhere without the `.PEEK` modifier?

Comment: You are correct, I had another hidden FETCH command elsewhere, causing this issue. Amazing how the obvious things catch us out sometimes. Thanks a lot!